# Moving files of the same name, cleaning up folder structure

Tags: files, macos

I was running a bioinformatics pipeline and now I am trying to clean up a bunch of unnecessary files and reorganize the folder structure. The files I was interested in all follow the same naming convention and have the same ending, so I was able to use rsync to get rid of the unnecessary files and get rid of the newly emptied directories easily.

Now I would like to reorganize my folder structure to simplify it. The current folder structure looks like this:

```
DirName1
|__L1
|    |__DirName1
|         |__seq
|              |__WA
|                   |__L1.txt
|__L2
|    |__DirName1
|         |__seq
|              |__WA
|                   |__L2.txt
|__L3
|    |__DirName1
|         |__seq
|              |__WA
|                  |__L3.txt
|__etc. 


DirName2
|__L1
|    |__DirName2
|         |__seq
|              |__WA
|                   |__L1.txt
|__L2
|    |__DirName2
|         |__seq
|              |__WA
|                   |__L2.txt
|__L3
|    |__DirName2
|         |__seq
|              |__WA
|                  |__L3.txt
|__etc. 


DirName3, DirName4 and so on...
```

The directories DirName, I am using as placeholders for specific sample names. Both the main directories and subdirectories within each one are named this way. Its essential that I don't lose these names because everything else is identical. I would like to clean up the unnecessary folder structure so that it to looks like this:

```
DirName1
|__L1.txt
|__L2.txt
|__L3.txt

DirName2
|__L1.txt
|__L2.txt
|__L3.txt
```

I haven't been able to find a solution that works on my own for something that I feel should be fairly easy. I am also working on a MacOs so I have also encountered limitations because I cannot use GNU version of find, though I could just be approaching this the wrong way.